# faster method for comparing two lists element-wise

Tags: python-3.x, database

I am building a relational DB using python. So far I have two tables, as follows:

```
>>> df_Patient.columns
[1] Index(['NgrNr', 'FamilieNr', 'DosNr', 'Geslacht', 'FamilieNaam', 'VoorNaam',
       'GeboorteDatum', 'PreBirth'],
      dtype='object')


>>> df_LaboRequest.columns
[2] Index(['RequestId', 'IsComplete', 'NgrNr', 'Type', 'RequestDate', 'IntakeDate',
       'ReqMgtUnit'],
      dtype='object')
```

The two tables are quite big:

```
>>> df_Patient.shape
[3] (386249, 8)

>>> df_LaboRequest.shape
[4] (342225, 7)
```

column `NgrNr` on `df_LaboRequest` if foreign key (FK) and references the homonymous column on `df_Patient`. In order to avoid any integrity error, I need to make sure that all the values under `df_LaboRequest[NgrNr]` are in `df_Patient[NgrNr]`.

With list comprehension I tried the following (to pick up the values that would throw an error):

```
[x for x in list(set(df_LaboRequest['NgrNr'])) if x not in list(set(df_Patient['NgrNr']))]
```

Though this is taking ages to complete. Would anyone recommend a faster method (*method* as a general word, as synonym for for *procedure*, nothing to do with the pythonic meaning of method) for such a comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One-liners aren't always better.
2. Don't check for membership in lists. Why on earth would you create a `set` (which is the recommended data structure for O(1) membership checks) and then cast it to a list which has O(N) membership checks?
3. Make the set of `df_Patient` *once* outside the list comprehension and use that instead of making the set in every iteration

```
patients = set(df_Patient['NgrNr'])
lab_requests = set(df_LaboRequest['NgrNr'])
result = [x for x in lab_requests if x not in patients]
```

Or, if you like to use [set operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set), simply find the [*difference* of both sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference):

```
result = lab_requests - patients
```

4. Alternatively, use `pandas` `isin()` function.

```
patients = patients.drop_duplicates()
lab_requests = lab_requests.drop_duplicates()
result = lab_requests[~lab_requests.isin(patients)]
```

Let's test how much faster these changes make the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import timeit

# Make dummy dataframes of patients and lab_requests
randoms = [random.randint(1, 1000) for _ in range(10000)]

patients = pd.DataFrame("patient{0}".format(x) for x in randoms[:5000])[0]
lab_requests = pd.DataFrame("patient{0}".format(x) for x in randoms[2000:8000])[0]

# Do it your way
def fun1(pat, lr): 
    return [x for x in list(set(lr)) if x not in list(set(pat))]

# Do it my way: Set operations
def fun2(pat, lr):
    pat_s = set(pat)
    lr_s = set(lr)
    return lr_s - pat_s

# Or explicitly iterate over the set
def fun3(pat, lr):
    pat_s = set(pat)
    lr_s = set(lr)
    return [x for x in lr_s if x not in pat_s]

# Or using pandas
def fun4(pat, lr):
    pat = pat.drop_duplicates()
    lr = lr.drop_duplicates()
    return lr[~lr.isin(pat)]

# Make sure all 3 functions return the same thing
assert set(fun1(patients, lab_requests)) == set(fun2(patients, lab_requests)) == set(fun3(patients, lab_requests)) == set(fun4(patients, lab_requests))

# Time it
timeit.timeit('fun1(patients, lab_requests)', 'from __main__ import patients, lab_requests, fun1', number=100)
# Output: 48.36615000000165

timeit.timeit('fun2(patients, lab_requests)', 'from __main__ import patients, lab_requests, fun2', number=100)
# Output: 0.10799920000044949

timeit.timeit('fun3(patients, lab_requests)', 'from __main__ import patients, lab_requests, fun3', number=100)
# Output: 0.11038020000069082

timeit.timeit('fun4(patients, lab_requests)', 'from __main__ import patients, lab_requests, fun4', number=100)
# Output: 0.32021789999998873
```

Looks like we have a ~150x speedup with `pandas` and a ~500x speedup with set operations!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a pandas installed right now to try this. But you could try removing the `list(..)` cast. I don't think it provides anything meaningful to the program and sets are much faster for lookup, e.g. `x in set(...)`, than lists.

Also you could try doing this with the pandas API rather than lists and sets, sometimes this faster. Try searching for `unique`. Then you could compare the size of the two columns and if it is the same, sort them and do an equality check.